# Error while creating home directory for a user using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, user-accounts

I have seen the following as a suggestion to create home directory for a user. So I have tried the following script to create a home directory :

```
 $sec_password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'Password' -AsPlainText -Force;
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList 'BLR2202710\Administrator', $sec_password;
Start-Process cmd /c -WindowStyle Hidden -Credential $credential -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;  
$user = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/cimv2 -Class win32_useraccount -Filter "LocalAccount=True AND Name='account17'";
$userprofile = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/cimv2 -Class win32_userprofile -Filter "SID='$($user.sid)' ";
$userprofile.localpath;
```

But it fails with the following exception : 
'Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand'

I am getting the issue in

```
Start-Process cmd /c -WindowStyle Hidden -Wait -Credential $credential    
    -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
```

Comment: I don't see your code creating a home directory anywhere. The line throwing the error (on PowerShell v2, works on v3) will just spawn and immediately terminate a `CMD` process.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: if the `cmd` process is launched in the target user's context, that might be enough to force Windows to create the profile ("home") directory.  (I'm not sure.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston With explicit credentials provided the process should be running in the context of the user `BLR2202710\Administrator`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: well spotted, that's probably the OP's problem.

Comment: I tried the above script with a modification :

Start-Process cmd  -Credential $credential -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;  


I am getting the error : 'This command cannot be executed due to the error: Access is denied.' What are the permissions required to create home directory?

Comment: That depends on where you want to create it and what the permissions on that folder are.